Bathroom circuit separation
I want to run a 20 amp circuit to the upstairs and downstairs bathroom outlets.  House built in 1986 has a 15 amp circuit to these outlets, one of which is GFCI, that also feed some lights.  During my research I found out that from the second (upstairs) bathroom outlet and lighting there is one more feed to an outside outlet.  Optimum would be to add this to the new 20 amp circuit but fishing 12 gauge wire to that location is not easily achieved.  Can I just change that outside outlet to a 15 amp GFCI and leave it on the 15 amp circuit?  Other options?  Thanks.

You have to find out how the it is wired.  A GFCI receptacle/device at the beginning will protect all devices down stream, if wired right.  Having more than one GFCI receptacle on a circuit can be a PITA.  You can have 12 gauge wire on a 15 amp circuit, but the circuit is still only 15 amp max.  A 20 amp circuit must only have 12 gauge wire for the whole circuit, no 14 gauge wire on it.

The Outdoor outlet is at the end of the current 15 amp circuit.  If I remove the other bathroom outlets by placing them in their own new 20 amp circuit then the remaining outside outlet would remain on the 15 amp circuit that also feeds some bathroom lighting.  Just need to know if the outside outlet now needs to be a 15 amp GFCI since it will no longer be protected from the bathroom GFCI outlet.  I understand that if the outdoor GFCI trips then some of the bathroom lights will also go out.

An outdoor receptacle needs to be GFCI protected, but usually better to keep GFCI protection inside of the house.  GFCIs and weather usually shortens their life.

Are you finding that the breaker trips or something?

AFIK code would allow an outside receptacle to be on the same circuit as bathroom lights. So you should be able to put a 15 A GFCI receptacle in the outside box. If this GFCI receptacle is at the end of the line, then if it trips it would not interrupt power to the bathroom lights.

Current code requires receptacle circuits for bathrooms to only feed bathrooms and they must be 20A and the receptacles must be GFCI-protected. But those are relatively new requirements and old circuits are grandfathered.
When you add things, you have to meet current code for anything new and you can't make anything "worse". So, for example, you could upgrade a 15A bathroom-shared-with-other-places circuit by adding GFCI protection, but you can't add additional receptacles because that is making the "receptacle circuit shared with other locations" problem worse.
In your situation:

Adding a 20A receptacle circuit exclusively for the bathrooms is a great idea. No other receptacles (old or new) should be on that circuit. It must be GFCI-protected - either at the breaker or the first receptacle (usually less expensive) is fine.
The existing 15A circuit can be either left in place or you can separate the non-bathroom part of the circuit. Depending on the wiring path, the simplest way to separate it may be to remove the bathroom receptacles that are currently on the circuit but leave the wires (now simply joined together instead of "chained" via the receptacles) in place. GFCI protection is required for outside receptacles, which you can do using either a GFCI/receptacle at the first outside receptacle (easy, but beware that even weather-resistant GFCI/receptacles may not last that long) or at a prior location in the circuit including the easy (provided your panel can handle it) way of a GFCI/breaker.

